# using model class name "Class" in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have table name "classes" in database and when i create model with name "Class" ,it gives syntax error (obviously).Is there any way to remove  this error without changing name of table in database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stay away from a model named "Class", it is a [keyword of php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) and it <strike>may</strike> *will* (as pointed by @AD7six) cause trouble if instantiated like that.

You can do the following:

```
class MyClass extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'classes';
}
```

Be sure that the controller ClassesController calls `MyClass` (with `$uses`), but besides that, you can use the model like any other model without worrying about reserved keywords.

Comment: may -> it does (it's a parse error - as also mentioned in the question). Worth mentioning associations can be aliased `$hasMany => array('Class' => array('className' => 'MyClass'));` +1 for including an example.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the name I used but I had a similar issue with cakephp and after some looking online it worked out to be so much easier to just change the table name. The naming conventions are quite strict and creating a work-around for this isn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a different name for your model and then link that model to your table using [useTable](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/de/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#usetable)

hope that helps